# GCP AutoML Vision API: Is there an api available to check the status of training for a specific Model?

Tags: status, training-data, automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

I am able to successfully start the training of a model with the code:

```
autoMlClient.createModelAsync(location, googleModel).get()
```

Is there an api endpoint I can call to get that status of the training for this specific model?

I'd like to know:

1. is training for this model complete?
2. is training still running?
3. how long until training is complete?
4. was there an error?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this (https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.operations/list) would contain the information you need?

Comment: Thank-you for your help! 

That may work.  

The documentation on the page you linked to states to use a GET request to https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{name}/operations where name is:

> The name of the operation's parent resource.

It's not clear to me how to obtain this name.  Any ideas?

Thanks!